# How to avoid VLOOKUP Error 1004 upon clearing data?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am starting my first user form in Excel.

I have a ComboBox, which uses a dropdown list to select a value. Once this value is selected it uses VLOOKUP to display the rest of the data in textboxes.

Upon using my reset button on the form, or trying to take out the data in these textboxes, it gives the VLOOKUP runtime error because the data is no longer there.

What do I have to do to stop this from happening?

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim MyTableArray As Range, MyEmpID As String

    Set MyTableArray = Sheets("CompressorData").Range("A:D")
    Me.txtName.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 2, 0)
    Me.TextBox3.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 1, 0)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 4, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the error you're trying to avoid (and just that), then include on 'On Error' statement like so:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
Dim MyTableArray As Range, MyEmpID As String


    Set MyTableArray = Range("A:D")
    On Error GoTo err_trap
    DropDown1.txtName.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DropDown1.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 2, 0)
    DropDown1.TextBox3.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DropDown1.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 1, 0)
    DropDown1.TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DropDown1.ComboBox1, MyTableArray, 4, 0)

err_trap:
    MsgBox ("Caught the error - delete msgbox in VB code and replace with 'Exit Sub' to avoid seeing this message box! hardy har captain")
    Exit Sub
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - that worked. But i still hear the sound as if it wants to pop up the error but avoids it haha. Whilst this does what i require, is there an alternative method that is better practice?

Comment: Strange that you still here sound - did you remove the msgbox() and replace with 'Exit Sub()'?

Comment: You could also go 'On Error Resume Next' and remove the ErrTrap altogether... Nothing wrong with this in terms of 'best practice' although it does mean you may be unaware of other types of errors.  But for the most part, it's the error you want to avoid, so the error you shall avoid!

Comment: Only other thing I would recommend is including the vlookups within excel and wrapping 'iferror() around them...hope that works and if so, consider reflecting via up/downvote as you deem fit! ta :)

Comment: Move the `Exit Sub` to above the the `err_trap:` line. Error handling should be outside the main body of code - after `Exit Sub`, but before `End Sub`.  Better still, use [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and check that a value is found before looking at the offset cells.

Comment: Hi - I never actually knew that - always used it as an 'escape clause' - I guess it comes after the Exit Sub so that you can actually handle the error, else all is 'lost/erased'?